# C++ variable initializes even though the copy constructor is deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, compiler-errors, initialization

The code below works unexpectedly!

```
class CameraBuffer;
class CameraBufferAccessor{
  friend CameraBuffer;
  private:
    CameraBufferAccessor(const int &data, const int &mutex);
  public:
    CameraBufferAccessor() = default;
    CameraBufferAccessor(const CameraBufferAccessor &) = delete;
    CameraBufferAccessor(CameraBufferAccessor &&) = delete;
    void operator=(const CameraBufferAccessor &other) = delete;
    void operator=(CameraBufferAccessor &&other) = delete;
};
class CameraBuffer {
  public:
    const CameraBufferAccessor getReadAccess() const {
        return {1, 2};
    }
};
int main() {
    auto buffer = CameraBuffer();
    CameraBufferAccessor a = buffer.getReadAccess();
    CameraBufferAccessor b = a;
```

here `CameraBufferAccessor b = a;` as expected throws error since copy constructor is explicitly deleted.

but something happens that i donot expect and i have searching for it so far no explaianation.
the line `CameraBufferAccessor a = buffer.getReadAccess();` just works although it uses a function which
has non-reference return, which itself is supposed to make use of Copy Constructor, secondly the returned `CameraBufferAccessor` should be copied into `a` initializing `a` using Copy/Move constructor once again, but it compiles and doesn't throw.

I heard That the compiler for optimization purposes is allowed to bypass copy construction when necessary,
if that's the case here, how am I supposed to tell when compiler does that?

I thought that it was due to the curly braces in return statement of `getReadAccess` which directly initialized the return value, So I tried `return CameraBufferAccessor(1, 2)`; but it still works. maybe compiler optimization?

Comment: Which compiler and how are you compiling it?

Comment: This code does not compile for me unless using C++17.  Guaranteed RVO in C++17 means `CameraBufferAccessor a = buffer.getReadAccess();` is replaced with `CameraBufferAccessor a{1, 2}` so no copy/move happens.  That said, `CameraBufferAccessor b = a;` still fails in C++17 because of the deleted assignment operator

Comment: Side note: Do not return class types by `const` value. It makes certain optimizations impossible. Drop the `const` from the return type of `getReadAccess()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty tricky one, but I think I have an answer.

You don't want user to intialise `CameraBufferAccessor`, so you did a private constructor, default constructor and copy constructor. To test, you deleted every constructor except the private one : `CameraBufferAccessor(const int &data, const int &mutex);`. So when you try to initialise with `CameraBufferAccessor a = buffer.getReadAccess();`, you pass it to a friend static class, and static method can access private constructors :

```
class CameraBuffer {
public:
    const CameraBufferAccessor getReadAccess() const {
        return {1, 2};
    }
};
```

Friended here :

```
class CameraBufferAccessor{
friend CameraBuffer;
//...
```

I hope I helped you to better understand why you can access your constructor.

Comment: I think the issue here is actually about the function that returns an object **by value**, and why that doesn't appear to invoke the (deleted) copy constructor for the object's class.